# Java return to position N in call stack

Tags: java, return, callstack

Using the `return` keyword in Java code will return execution to the last piece of calling code in the call stack. If object `foo` calls `baz.bar()`, the `return` keyword in the `bar` method will continue code execution in `foo`.

Let's say I have object `foo` that calls `foofoo` that calls `foofoofoo` in the above scenario, and `foofoofoo` calls `baz.bar()`. Is there anyway in Java to use the `return` keyword, or something else, so that the code in the `bar` method can return all the way back up to `foo`?

(WITHOUT THROWING AN EXCEPTION)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, this is not possible. You'll have to handle this yourself by code, one level at a time (an exception will do the same, it's just automated a bit more).

However, it's probably not a good idea to do this anyway. Suppose that you suddenly need to call `baz.bar()` from `quux`, without touching `foo` at all. What should now happen if `bar` tries to return to `foo`, which is not in the call stack? If you just want it to go up N levels, can you imagine the problems that might happen if you merge `foofoofoo` into `foofoo`, or change it to add a `foofoofoofoo`, without remembering to modify `bar`?

An exception sounds exactly like the right tool for this job: `baz.bar()` shouldn't care that it has to go to `foo`, it should know something *exceptional* has occurred, requiring it to abort what it's doing, and then `foo` should know that this exceptional situation can occur and handle it (even if it's just doing nothing is this case). If it's to avoid having to add a throws clause to everything, use an unchecked exception instead.

Comment: It's not to avoid a throws clause, it just seems alot to me like using Exceptions for control flow.

Comment: If you are able to check for this criteria before all of this, then you can do that instead - but sometimes, that just can't be determined in advance, and you'll have to throw the exception if it doesn't work out.

Answer (score 1):

Fortunately this is impossible in Java.

There are rare cases where similar things make sense, for example when you do context switching in an OS kernel.

But it is absolutely the wrong thing to do in application programs.

Comment: I didn't think it was possible to be honest, probably quite rightly so.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not a huge Java guy, so I can't say for sure, but this does not sound like a safe thing to do and I would doubt that this would be supported in Java.

Now were this C/C++, you could make a dirty little hack that would overwrite the return address on the stack...

Comment: Were this C/C++ my life would be full of dirty little hacks, I'm sure. :-) However, you may have a point.

Comment: @Finbarr Whereas in Java we cleanly rewrite the bytecode on class load.